# Closed form of $\int_0^\pi \frac{1}{(1+\sin x)^n} d x$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals

Starting with the simplest one, we can rationalize the denominator first.
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_1& =\int_0^\pi \frac{1}{1+\sin x} d x \\
& =\int_0^\pi \frac{1-\sin x}{\cos ^2 x} d x \\
& =\int_0^\pi\left(\sec ^2 x-\sec x \tan x\right) d x \\
& =[\tan x-\sec x]_0^\pi \\
& =2
\end{aligned}
$$

As the power increases, this method is rather long and I started to use half-angle formula of cosine.
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_2 & =2 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{(1+\sin x)^2} d x \\
& =2 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{(1+\cos x)^2} d x \\
& =2 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\left(2 \cos ^2 \frac{x}{2}\right)^2} d x \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sec ^4 \frac{x}{2} d x \\& =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sec ^4 x d x \\
& =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\left(1+\tan ^2 x\right) d(\tan x) \\
& =1+\frac{1}{3}\\
& =\frac{4}{3}
\end{aligned}
$$

Then I try to generalize the result for $I_n$ similarly.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^\pi \frac{d x}{(1+\sin x)^n} & =\frac{1}{2^{n-2}} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sec ^{2 n} x d x \\
& =\frac{1}{2^{n-2}} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\left(1+\tan ^2 x\right)^{n-1} d(\tan x) \\
& =\frac{1}{2^{n-2}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}  \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\begin{array}{c}
n-1 \\
k
\end{array}\right) \tan^{2k} x d(\tan x) \\
& =\frac{1}{2^{n-2}} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\begin{array}{c}
n-1 \\
k
\end{array}\right) \frac{1}{2 k+1}
\end{aligned}
$$

**Is there any other simpler answer or method?**

Comments and alternatives are highly appreciated.

Comment: *Mathematica*:  $$2^{1-n}
   \left(B_1\left(\frac{1}{2}-n,\frac{1}{2}\right)-B_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{2}-n,\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$$, where $B$ is a Bessel function.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork. Bessel ??

Comment: Note that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}k\frac1{2k+1}=\int_0^1\left(x^2+1\right)^{n-1}\mathrm dx\;.$$

Comment: Yes, it can be obtained by putting $u=\tan x$.

Comment: [Solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=2%5E%281+-+%283+n%29%2F2%29+Γ%281%2F2+-+n%29+%28%282%5E%28n%2F2%29+sqrt%28π%29%29%2FΓ%281+-+n%29-2%5E%281%2F4%29+legendrep%28n-1%2F2%2Cn-1%2F2%2C1%2F√2%29%29%2C++2%5E%281-n%29beta%281%2F2%2C1%2F2%2C+1%2F2+-+n%29%2C++2%5E%281-n%29%28beta%281%2F2+-+n%2C+1%2F2%29+-+beta%281%2F2%2C+1%2F2+-+n%2C+1%2F2%29%29) without incomplete beta function for fun

Answer (score 4):

There is a straightforward recurrence relation. I think (slight correction to your result) that $$I_n=\frac{1}{2^{n-2}}\int_0^{\frac{1}{4}\pi} \sec^{2n}x\,dx.$$ Then integrating by parts gives $$I_n=\frac{1}{2^{n-2}}\left[\tan x \sec^{2n-2}x\right]_0^{\frac{1}{4}\pi}-\frac{1}{2^{n-2}}\int_0^{\frac{1}{4}\pi} (2n-2)\tan^2x \sec^{2n-2}x\,dx,$$ which is $$I_n=2 - 2(n-1)I_n+(n-1)I_{n-1}$$ (using $\tan^2 x = \sec^2 x -1$), so $$I_n=\frac{2+(n-1)I_{n-1}}{2n-1}.$$

You can write this as a sum: $$I_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{2^{r+1}{n \choose r}^2}{{2r \choose r}{2n \choose 2r}},$$
(which reduces to the series you found) though I can't see an obvious closed form for this - and I'd be surprised if there was one, given the Beta function expression.

Comment: Thank you for your recursive relation.  Can we use it to find a closed form?

Answer (score 2):

There is an antiderivative in terms of the Gaussian hypergeometric function. This can be reduced to an incomplete beta function
$$I_n=\int\frac{dx}{(1+\sin( x))^n} =2^{-n} \sec(x)\,\sqrt{\cos ^2(x)}  B_{\frac{\sin   (x)+1}{2} }\left(\frac{1-2n}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
$$J_n=\int_0^{t<\frac \pi 2}\frac{dx}{(1+\sin(x))^n}=2^{-n} \left(B_{\frac{\sin
   (t)+1}{2} }\left(\frac{1-2n}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)-B_{\frac{1}{2}}\left
   (\frac{1-2n}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$$
$$J_n=\int_0^{t>\frac \pi 2}\frac{dx}{(1+\sin(x))^n}=-2^{-n} \left(B_{\frac{\sin
   (t)+1}{2} }\left(\frac{1-2n}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)+B_{\frac{1}{2}}\left
   (\frac{1-2n}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$$
$$K_n=\int_0^{\pi }\frac{dx}{(1+\sin(x))^n}=2^{1-n}
   \left(B_1\left(\frac{1-2n}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)-B_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(
   \frac{1-2n}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$$
This generates the sequence
$$\left\{2,\frac{4}{3},\frac{14}{15},\frac{24}{35},\frac{166}{315},\frac
   {292}{693},\frac{1046}{3003},\frac{1904}{6435},\frac{28102}{10939
   5},\frac{52412}{230945},\frac{65734}{323323},\frac{124520}{676039},\cdots
   \right\}$$

Comment: Claude Leibovici, One more lesson from you.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

**By Incomplete Beta Function**

I continue my journey with $$I_n=\frac{1}{2^{n-2}} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sec ^{2 n} x d x$$
Letting $t=\cos^2 x$ transforms the integral into an incomplete Beta functions as:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sec ^{2 n} x d x & =\frac{1}{2} \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 t^{-n-\frac{1}{2}}\left(1-t^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} d t \\
& =\frac{1}{2}\left[B\left(\frac{1}{2}-n, \frac{1}{2}\right)-B_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{2}-n, \frac{1}{2}\right)\right]\\ OR&=\frac 12 B_\left(\frac{1}{2}, 1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}-n, \frac{1}{2}\right)\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Now we can express the integral as
$$
\boxed{\int_0^\pi \frac{1}{(1+\sin x)^n} d x= \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\left[B\left(\frac{1}{2}-n, \frac{1}{2}\right)-B_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{2}-n, \frac{1}{2}\right)\right] }
$$
which agrees with both Claude Leibovici and Mathematica.

Comment: What is $B(1/2-n,1/2)$ for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$? I.e., what is your definition of the beta function for negative argument? The integral definition holds only for ones with positive real parts.

Comment: Sorry; there is another [simplification](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=+beta%281%2F2+-+n%2C+1%2F2%29+-+beta%281%2F2%2C+1%2F2+-+n%2C+1%2F2%29%2C+beta%281%2F2%2C+1%2F2%2C+1%2F2+-+n%29)

Comment: I would guess that $B(1/2 - n,1/2) = \Gamma (1/2 - n)\Gamma (1/2)/\Gamma (1 - n) = 0$ for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$.